# Как правильно создавать GUI формы в IDEA?

Tags: gui, java, intellij-idea, swing

Пытаюсь создать форму в IDEA с помощью дефолтного плагина. Версия IDE 11.0.1.

Делаю так:

1. Создаю проект.
2. Создаю в нем форму.
3. В настройках указываю Generate GUI into Java source code.
4. Потом добавляю форму, добавляю кнопки и т.д.
5. Запускаю проект - генерируются какие-то строчки.

Вот код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Jakeroid
 * Date: 30.01.12
 * Time: 22:52
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class MainForm {
    private JButton button1;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextArea textArea1;

    {
// GUI initializer generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
// >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
// DO NOT EDIT OR ADD ANY CODE HERE!
        $$$setupUI$$$();
    }

    /**
     * Method generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
     * >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
     * DO NOT edit this method OR call it in your code!
     *
     * @noinspection ALL
     */
    private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
        final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(2, 3, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setText("Button");
        panel1.add(button1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, null, null, 0, false));
        textField1 = new JTextField();
        panel1.add(textField1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 0, 1, 2, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_WEST, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, new Dimension(150, -1), null, 0, false));
        textArea1 = new JTextArea();
        panel1.add(textArea1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 3, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, null, new Dimension(150, 50), null, 0, false));
    }
}
```

Приложение не запускается, ошибка:

> Cannot resolve method.

Подсвечиваются строки, сгенерированные IDEA.

Comment: а где класс с методом main() и run()?

Comment: А то есть без них, IDEA не генерирует код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в общем так:

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame{
    private JButton button1;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextArea textArea1;

    private void setupUI() {
        final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(2, 3, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setText("Button");
        panel1.add(button1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, null, null, 0, false));
        textField1 = new JTextField();
        panel1.add(textField1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 0, 1, 2, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_WEST, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, new Dimension(150, -1), null, 0, false));
        textArea1 = new JTextArea();
        panel1.add(textArea1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 3, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, null, new Dimension(150, 50), null, 0, false));
        setSize(500, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
    public static void main(String [] args){  
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){ 
                    public void run(){new MainForm().setupUI();}
      }
    );
    }
}
```

И вообще советую почитать хотя бы [эту](http://skipy.ru/technics/gui_int.html) статью или купить [книгу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5774933/) Swing-эффективные пользовательские интерфейсы издание-2 Портянкин Иван.

Comment: Дело в том, что я могу создавать формы без GUI дизайнера. Меня интересовала именно проблема IDEA.

Comment: видимо он просто ограничен созданим форм и всё, остальное, по всей видимости, ты должен сам доделывать =)

Comment: Разобрался с генератором кода кстати?)

Comment: Неа. Не разобрался. Если нужно, пишу вручную. Так и то проще.

Answer (score 1):

Некропост и все такое, но поделюсь своим велосипедом 3 итерации. По ходу проекта нужно было создавать много внутренних окон, по этому решил пойти через абстрактный класс. Само окно содается средставми JIdea, просто добавляется наследование абстрактного класса. Переопределяем метод getRootPanel(), в котором возвращаем самый верхний JPanel, который и станет нашим contentPane. 
Затем во внешнем классе просто вызываем ManagebleWindow.getInstance(НужныйНамКлассОкна.class) и все.

В велосипеде v.2 я просто наследовал JInternalFrame а всю инициализацию выносил в переопределенный метод setVisible(), потому как конструктор отрабатывает раньше, чем генерируется сам GUI, но этот велосипед не переживал mvn:clean - просто переставал запускаться и нужно было вручную дергать каждое окно всякими бубнами, чтобы оно начало работать (что там происходило я так и не разобрался), а этот велосипед спокойно переживает mvn:clean

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public abstract class ManageableWindow extends JInternalFrame {

public ManageableWindow(String title) {
    super(title, true, true, true, true);
}

protected void init(JPanel contentPane) {
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    createForm();
    createMenu();
    createListeners();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(getMinimumDimension());
    pack();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation((screenSize.width - getWidth()) / 2, (screenSize.height - getHeight()) / 2);
}

protected Dimension getMinimumDimension() {
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}

protected abstract JPanel getBasePanel();

protected abstract void createMenu();

protected abstract void createForm();

protected abstract void createListeners();

public Object getParam() {
    return null;
}

public static ManageableWindow getInstance(Class<? extends ManageableWindow> aClass) {
    ManageableWindow window = null;
    try {
        window = aClass.newInstance();
        window.init(window.getBasePanel());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return window;
}

}
```