# Создание GUI на Java в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, swing, gui

Создаю новый проект, в нем класс и форму, добавляю в `JPanel` кнопку, но почему-то не могу ни поменять её размер, ни перетащить в другое место на панели, с чем может быть связано и как это лечить?

`Java source code` уже отметила в настройках. Что ещё можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно создавать GUI формы в IDEA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75883/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-gui-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-idea)

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я вижу вы используете BorderLayout, этот менеджер не подходит под ваши задачи,потому что этот менеджер располагает элементы по 4 основынм направлениям и в центре (North, South, East, West, Center),при этом растягивая элементы на всю доступную длину и ширину. Попробуйте использовать другой

Answer (score 0):

Это кодом лечить надо. `GUI` конструктор для `SWING` в `IDEA` работает криво. В нем можно только основные объекты накидать, а все остальное в коде.